# jQuery plugin to page text on overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css, client-side

I have a fixed width and height div which will hold an amount of text. If the text overflows the div, I need it to appear in a paging basis, whereby dots at the bottom of the page would denote how many pages there were. Similar to that of slideshows.

Does anyone have any ideas of a plugin for jQuery which would allow me to do this? The only ones I can find, are based on un-ordered lists, and ask you to specify the number of items, which doesn't really fit my requirements. I do not want a scroll bar at the bottom.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote up a small fiddle which will do what you need it to do. A little styling will be in order but the functionality is there.

The code calculates how many pages there are based on the viewport of the div and the height of the text and then creates an unordered list for clicking.

When the user clicks on one of the li's in the list it will take that li's index as the page and scroll the outer fixed div down the index * viewport height.

http://jsfiddle.net/ydPfE/2/

I hope this helps :).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a real help, and much more than I was expecting! I am quite a jQuery beginner so this will be a good lesson to learn with regards to doing things like this.

Comment: A simple and elegant solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a plugin that does this, but if you can't find one here's how I'd begin to approach the problem:

Assuming you have a slideshow plugin that supports full html in divs, I would count either characters or words to split the text into chunks - each chunk would go into a div that the slideshow would use.

The drawback is that this isn't precise and you would have to give yourself room for words wrapping differently. I'm not sure how to get around that but hopefully this gives you a starting point.